# Inserting data from forms to access by ODBC

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I have try to use ODBC to insert data. However, it does not work

This is my code. How can I solve the problem?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   $ContactPersonID=$_POST['ContactPersonID']
$FirstName=$_POST['First name'];
$LastName=$_POST['Last name'];
$PhoneNumber=$_POST['PhoneNumber'];
$RestaurantID=$_POST['RestaurantID'];
echo $ContactPersonID ." ".$FirstName." ".$LastName." ".$PhoneNumber." ".$PhoneNumber." ".$RestaurantID ;
$con=odbc_connect("Online Food  Delivery Database","", "");
$sql="INSERT INTO RestaurantPeopleContact 
    (ContactPersonID,FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,RestaurantID) 
    VALUES ('$ContactPersonID','$FirstName','$LastName','$FirstName','$PhoneNumber','$RestaurantID')";

if(odbc_exec($con,$sql))
{
    echo "Data saved.";
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Nevertheless, its appreciated to see the error instead of figuring it.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting twice the firstname.
By this reason, the columns declaration doesnt match with the number of variables

Comment: but the Microsoft Access's database still not reflect the queries. Is it the problem of connection between ODBC?

Comment: Sorry friend but with the vague information that you provide is difficult to know what are you talking about. The only thing I see clear is you are trying to insert more columns than the declaration (Firstname twice)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for the MS Access connection, a better handler to pass parameters and raise needed exceptions and of course to avoid SQL injection especially from web input. You may need to initialize PDO in your .ini file.

Also, *ContactPersonID* and *RestaurantID* might be integer values but you look to be quoting them. Parameters help in defining needed data types without worrying about quote enclosures or messy string concatenation.

```
$ContactPersonID = $_POST['ContactPersonID']
$FirstName = $_POST['First name'];
$LastName = $_POST['Last name'];
$PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
$RestaurantID = $_POST['RestaurantID'];

$database = "C:\Path\To\Database\Online Food Delivery Database.accdb";

# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PLACEHOLDERS
$sql = "INSERT INTO RestaurantPeopleContact 
        (ContactPersonID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, RestaurantID) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:DSN=MS Access Database;DBq=$database;");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);  

    # BIND PARAMETERS
    $sth->bindParam(1, $ContactPersonID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $FirstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(3, $LastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(4, $PhoneNumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindParam(5, $RestaurantID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $sth->execute(); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
# close the connection
$dbh = null;
```